# How to anchor a Floating Action Button to the App ToolBar like in the guide images?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to get a Floating Action Button anchored to the upper part of my activity, on the action bar. In the guides is not explained how to get that effect of getting the floating action button anchored to the action bar and also getting the action bar moved with a smooth automatic effect when the user moves the screen.

That is what I want to achieve but I can't find the explanation. I'm using this layout, and by default It's positioned on the lower right part of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.Activity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_favorites" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_48dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here you can see very cute samples of Floating Action Buttons anchored to the upper action bars in some screenshots:

https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html#buttons-floating-action-button-floating-action-button

For example this:

[image]

Which changes are necessary to get that positioning and behaviour? Is there a sample or guide of how to achieve this?

Comment: https://www.androidauthority.com/using-coordinatorlayout-android-apps-703720/

Answer (score 2):

```
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_add_shopping_cart_white_24dp"
    android:theme="@style/PrimaryActionButton"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/bottom_sheet" //id of any view to anchor
    app:layout_anchorGravity="top|end" /> //position to anchor
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `app:layout_anchor` to tell the FAB to view which it should be anchored.

Use `app:layout_anchorGravity` to tell the FAB where on the view (the one it's anchored to) it should be positioned.

From https://material.io/components/android/catalog/coordinator-layout/:

> **Anchors**
>
> The app:layout_anchor attribute can be set on children of the
>   CoordinatorLayout to attach them to another view.
>   app:layout_anchorGravity can be used to specify where to anchor the
>   child on the other view. A good example of this is a floating action
>   button that is anchored to the bottom-right edge of an app bar:
>
> ```
> <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
>     android:id="@+id/coordinator_layout"
>     android:layout_width="match_parent"
>     android:layout_height="match_parent">
> ​
>   <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
>       android:id="@+id/app_bar"
>       android:layout_width="match_parent"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
> ​
>     <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
>         android:layout_width="match_parent"
>         android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>
> ​
>   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
> ​
>   <!-- Main content -->
> ​
>   <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
>       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>       android:layout_margin="16dp"
>       android:contentDescription="@string/add_item"
>       android:src="@drawable/ic_add_24dp"
>       app:layout_anchor="@id/app_bar"
>       app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
> ​
> </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
> ```

The moving the appbar when the user scrolls is achieved with a CollapsingToolbarLayout, as explained [here](https://material.io/components/android/catalog/collapsing-toolbar-layout/).